# exec to add a function into a class

Tags: python, exec, setattr

So I've looked at similar questions, and I've found some solutions to this, but I can't quite figure out how to do this.

What I'm trying to do is add a method to a class from a string. I can do this with the `setattr()` method, but that won't let me use `self` as an attribute in the extra method. Here's an example: (and I apologize for the variable names, I always use yolo when I'm mocking up an idea)

```
class what:
    def __init__(self):
        s = 'def yolo(self):\n\tself.extra = "Hello"\n\tprint self.extra'
        exec(s)
        setattr(self,"yolo",yolo)

what().yolo()
```

returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: yolo() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

and if `s = 'def yolo():\n\tself.extra = "Hello"\n\tprint self.extra'`
then I get this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in yolo
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

This essentially means that I cannot dynamically create methods for classes, which I know is bad practice and unpythonic, because the methods would be unable to access the variables that the rest of the class has access to.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: *Why* do you want to dynmically add methods to a class?

Comment: @Ivo Haha... Is because I can a good enough reason?

Comment: No, because it's completely unpythonic. I hear ruby loves that shit, though.

Comment: Just about everything in this question is a bad idea. And especially so for someone who hasn't bothered to learn how methods and locals and so on work before trying to write hacky code for no reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to bind your function to the class instance to turn it into a method. It can be done by wrapping it in [`types.MethodType`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.MethodType):

```
import types

class what:
    def __init__(self):
        s = 'def yolo(self):\n\tself.extra = "Hello"\n\tprint self.extra'
        exec(s)
        self.yolo = types.MethodType(yolo, self)

what().yolo()
```

On a side note, why do you even need `exec` in this case? You can just as well write

```
import types

class what:
    def __init__(self):
        def yolo(self):
            self.extra = "Hello"
            print self.extra

        self.yolo = types.MethodType(yolo, self)

what().yolo()
```

**Edit:** for the sake of completeness, one might prefer a solution through [the descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html):

```
class what:
    def __init__(self):
        def yolo(self):
            self.extra = "Hello"
            print self.extra

        self.yolo = yolo.__get__(self)

what().yolo()
```

Comment: THank you! I am just using this as proof of concept, so in this case I really don't need it, but it's more for the sake of the idea than practicality.

Comment: One side not I noticed, the code here doesn't allow for expandability as I have to declare the function in the `self.yolo = types...`line, I think I could use `exec()` to amend this, but I will have to check still.

Comment: If you want to set the attribute name dynamically, you can use ``setattr`` (as you did in the original code). I just wrote ``self.yolo = `` because the ``setattr`` with a string literal as the second argument is quite pointless.

Comment: @Hovestar: Any time you think "I could use `exec`…" you're almost certainly doing it wrong. Python has ways to dynamically reflect on almost anything without ever needing to use `exec`. All you're doing is making your code a little slower, a lot less readable, and a whole lot harder to debug, for absolutely no benefit. If you're writing a custom REPL or something else that obviously needs to execute strings, then use `exec`; in any other case, look for another way, and, if you can't find one, look again.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, seems more elegant to me:

```
class what:
    pass

ld = {}
exec("""
def yolo(self):
    self.extra = "Hello"
    print(self.extra)
""", None, ld)
# print('locals got: {}'.format(ld))
for name, value in ld.items():
    setattr(what, name, value)

what().yolo()
```