# Conditional execution without having to check repeatedly for a condition

Tags: python

I have a class with code that fits into the following template:

```
class aClass:

    def __init__(self, switch = False):
        self.switch = switch

    def f(self):
        done = False
        while not done:

            # a dozen lines of code

            if self.switch:
                # a single line of code

            # another dozen lines of code
```

So the single line of code in the if statement will either *never* be executed, or it will be executed in *all* iterations. And this is actually known as soon as the object is initialized.

When `self.switch` is `True`, I would like the single line of code to be executed without having to check for `self.switch` at every single iteration. And when `self.switch` is `False`, I would like the single line of code to be ignored, again without having to repeatedly check for `self.switch`.

I have of course considered writing *two versions* of `f` and selecting the appropriate one in `__init__` according to the value of the `switch`, but duplicating all this code except for a single line doesn't feel right.

Can anyone suggest an elegant way to solve this problem? Perhaps a way to *generate* the appropriate version of the `f` method at initialization?

Comment: unlike that single line of code is a real resource hog (like writing a large chunk of data to a file), processing an image. Just forget it. This is simply not worth the brain cells you are burning

Comment: I have simplified the description so that it is understandable. But the iteration is performed hundreds of thousands of times and the lines of code that are to be executed or bypassed are computationally expensive.

Comment: Confirm that by profiling. It maybe the most insignificant bit of code

Comment: I agree with @e4c5, especially since you have _dozens_ of lines before and after this single line.

Comment: Let me just clarify this: I am not asking the question in order to get feedback on how important it is to resolve this issue. My intention is to find out *if* there is a way to resolve this issue without duplicating code. In addition, I imagine that an answer might prove useful in other situations where this pattern arises.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `exec`. This question suggests how to dynamically add a method to a class using `exec`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19205608/4996248 . You could conditionally modify the string passed to `exec`. I'm not sure how the answers to this question could be modified to be used inside `__init__()`. If they can't -- you could perhaps have a custom initialization function that creates a class instance and then dynamically adds the appropriate method.

Comment: @JohnColeman The `exec` suggestion is very interesting and I looked into it. Regardless of how 'pythonic' it is (or isn't), it essentially allows you to assemble code (as a string) at execution time, which would certainly be a way to answer the question. Unfortunately my `f` function not only returns a result, it `yield`s results, so `exec` cannot be used. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment to my original question, [JohnColeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman) suggested using `exec` and provided a link to [another relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205608/exec-to-add-a-function-into-a-class).

That was an excellent suggestion and the solution I was lead to is:

```
_template_pre = """\
def f(self):
    for i in range(5):
        print("Executing code before the optional segment.")
"""

_template_opt = """\
        print("Executing the optional segment")
"""

_template_post = """\
        print("Executing code after the optional segment.")
"""

class aClass:

    def __init__(self, switch = False):
        if switch:
            fdef = _template_pre + _template_opt + _template_post
        else:
            fdef = _template_pre + _template_post
        exec(fdef, globals(), self.__dict__)
        # bind the function
        self.f = self.f.__get__(self)
```

You can verify this actually works:

```
aClass(switch = False).f()
aClass(switch = True).f()
```

Before jumping to conclusions as to how *"pythonic"* this is, let me point out that such an approach is employed in a couple of metaclass recipes I have encountered and even in the Python Standard Library (check [the implementation of namedtuple](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py), to name one example).

Answer (score 1):

That's a completely valid ask. If not for performance then for readability.

Extract the three pieces of logic (before, inside, and after your condition) in three separate methods and in `f()` just write two implementations of the big loop:

```
def first(self):
    pass

def second(self):
    pass

def third(self):
    pass

def f(self):
    if self.switch:
        while ...:
             self.first()
             self.third()
    else:
         while ...:
            self.first()
            self.second()
            self.third()
```

If you want it more elegant (although it depends on taste), you express the two branches of my `f()` into two methods `first_loop` and `second_loop` and then in `__init__` assign `self.f = self.first_loop` or `self.f = self.second_loop` depending on the `switch`:

```
class SuperUnderperformingAccordingToManyYetReadable(object):
    def __init__(self, switch):
        if self.switch:
            self.f = self._first_loop
        else:
            self.f = self._second_loop

    def _first(self):
        pass

    def _second(self):
        pass

    def _third(self):
        pass

    def _first_loop(self):
        while ...:
             self.first()
             self.third()

    def _second_loop(self):
         while ...:
            self.first()
            self.second()
            self.third()
```

You may need to do some extra work to manage breaking out of the while loop.

Comment: I think the overhead of the two function calls is likely more than the single if-test.

Comment: yes, building a call stack is a lot more work than an `if` and besides we don't know where the performance issue is in the original code or even if there is a performance issue at all because no profiling has been done

Comment: There is no performance issue. The whole discussion of performance was started by you. Complete diversion from the original problem. The OP only started talking about it because of your comment and he tried to justify that he has a valid problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the `.switch` attribute is not supposed to change, try to select the loop body dynamicly in the `__init__()` method:

```
def __init__(self, switch=False):
    self.switch = switch
    self.__fBody = self.__fSwitchTrue if switch else self.__fSwitchFalse
def f(self):
    self.__done = False
    while not self.__done:
        self.__fBody()
def __fSwitchTrue(self):
    self.__fBodyStart()
    ... # a single line of code
    self.__fBodyEnd()
def __fSwitchFalse(self):
    self.__fBodyStart()
    self.__fBodyEnd()
def __fBodyStart(self):
    ... # a dozen lines of code
def __fBodyEnd(self):
    ... # another dozen lines of code
```

Remember to change values used by more than one of the defined methods to attributes (like `done` is changed to `.__done`).